# How to create a variable from two other variables whose modalities are not mutually exclusive in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a database with two variables.
The first variable (matrimonial) indicates the matrimonial status of the individual (married or not).
The second variable (rela) gives the broader relationship status (in relationship or not).
I would like to create a variable that returns "married" for married individuals, "in a relationship" for individuals in a relationship, whether married or not, and "not in a relationship" for others.
I tried with case.when (see code below) but the "rela" variable overwrites the others. I end up with 9 individuals in a relationship and 1 without a relationship, but among those in a relationship I don't have the details of those who are married or not.
Can you help me to create such a variable?

```
library(dplyr)

matrimonial <- c("married", "non married","non married","married","married","non married","married","non married","married","married")
rela <- c("in relation", "in relation","no relation","in relation","in relation","in relation","in relation","in relation","in relation","in relation")

test <- data.frame(matrimonial, rela)

test$relational_status <- case_when(test$rela == "in relation" ~ "in relation",
                                    test$matrimonial == "married" ~ "married", 
                                    TRUE ~ "no relation")
table(test$relational_status)

in relation no relation 
          9           1
```

Comment: As written, you will never get "married" because all your married people are in relationships, and you've specified `"in a relationship" for individuals in a relationship, whether married or not`